# Parsing through GSON with Proguard

Tags: android, gson, proguard

I am having problems with GSON on Android with Proguard.
APK is compiled, installed on phone. 
Application is not crashing, it is just not parsing object correctly.

I log all the data and it is like that:

I get correct string with data to parse.

(CookieValue is correct)

```
Token token = new Gson().fromJson(cookieValue, Token.class);
```

After this line, I am logging this object and it is having only null values inside.

My Proguard GSON:

```
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }


-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer
-keep public class com.google.gson
```

Token rules:

```
 -dontwarn com.project.package.model.oauth.**

 -keep,allowshrinking class com.project.package.oauth.Token { *; }
```

Yes, I have tried this configuration https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
- keep,allowshrinking class com.project.package.oauth.Token { *; }
```

Do you actually have a space between the dash and keep?  If so, take that out and see if it helps.

You might also want to remove the space after the dash in the previous dontwarn line, as well.

Comment: No, I dont have these spaces. Post fixes. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in my collection :
https://github.com/thientvse/awesome-mobile-collections/blob/master/README.md

It will help you config almost lib in proguard file.
I hope it will help your problem!